# sidebar width too short to display datetimepicker

Tags: isis

[image: Click to see screenshot of Sidebar error displaying datetimepicker]

How can i solve this situation?

Comment: By showing code. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Apache Isis 1.17.0, take a look at

```
wicket/wicket/resource/org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.pages.SidebarCssResourceReference/simple-sidebar-ver-1582544091730.css
```

and try to modify values for padding / margin. Eventually you need to override settings in application.css; sometimes you may need to use '!important'

If you are using Chrome, press `<Ctrl>-<Shift>-C` and select the date-time widget.

If you can provide sample code, I could take a closer look.